# Первая программа на C++

Tags: c++

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello world!!!\n";
  _getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запустить программу в Microoft Visual Studio C++ 2010, Экспресс выпуск. ОС Windows XP Professional 2008 Edition, Service Pack 3.

Выдает следующую ошибку:

```
------ Построение начато: проект: 1, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1.cpp
c:\documents and settings\1\мои документы\visual studio 2010\projects\11\11\11.cpp(3): warning C4627: #include <iostream>: пропущен при поиске использования предкомпилированного заголовка
Добавление директивы в "StdAfx.h" или перестройка предкомпилированного заголовка
c:\documents and settings\1\мои документы\visual studio 2010\projects\11\11\11.cpp(4): warning C4627: #include <conio.h>: пропущен при поиске использования предкомпилированного заголовка
Добавление директивы в "StdAfx.h" или перестройка предкомпилированного заголовка
c:\documents and settings\1\мои документы\visual studio 2010\projects\11\11\11.cpp(14): fatal error C1010: непредвиденный конец файла во время поиска предкомпилированного заголовка. Возможно, вы забыли добавить директиву "#include "StdAfx.h"" в источник.
========== Построение: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 -=========
```

Comment: При создании проекта выбирайте "создать пустой проект", а не с дополнительными заголовками. Или добавить #include "StdAfx.h" в текущий файл, если не ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 3):

conio.h не будет работать в visual studio (по крайней мере в новых версиях).

conio.h устаревшая библиотека, которая уже мало где есть.

Используй функцию system("PAUSE") для просмотра результата.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello world!!!\n";
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

С этим проблем не должно возникнуть.

Comment: Да не нужен никакой system("pause"). В студии есть Ctrl + F5, чтобы окошко не закрывалось.

Comment: нажимаю Ctrl + F5, выводится сообщение: "для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу...". после нажатия окно закрывается. т. е. "hello world" не выводится. как добиться чтобы выводилось "hello world"?

Comment: из за чего так происходит????

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста! второй день не могу простейшую программу запустить(((

Comment: получилось. всем огромное спасибо!!!

Answer (score 3):

Давно не писал в VS, в последний раз еще в VS 2005

Ну и собственно там обязательно он требовал подключения

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
```

Тут тоже компилятор просит подключения этого файла.

В начале нужно добавить эту строку и все. в остальном программа должна отработать так как задумано.

Comment: При создании проекта можно было поставить галочку в Empty Project. Тогда stdafx.h не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <Windows.h> //(для system("PAUSE");)
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello world!!!\n";
  while(1){
       system("PAUSE");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: выводится сообщение: "для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу...". после нажатия окно закрывается.

Comment: ну да, а вы хотите чтобы оно не закрывалось вообще? тогда добавьте while(1){} до system("PAUSE");, а system("PAUSE"); уберите. Программа зациклится и закроется только нажатием по "Х"

Comment: дело в том что "hello world" так и не выводится! сразу пишет "для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу..."

Comment: эээ, не выводится? странно... Пробуй printf("HW!\n"); вместо cout << "Hello world!!!\n";

Comment: ну все равно результат тот же самый(

Comment: Подозреваю у вас странная студия, вот http://ideone.com/m2ZH48

Comment: студия с офф сайта майкрософт

Comment: Также можно так:
#include <cstdlib> //(для system("PAUSE");)